# dnf install completion not working with zsh, yet working with bash

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, dnf

In bash, if I type `dnf install java<tab>`, I get a bunch of suggestions of packages to install. However, if I do this in zsh, nothing happens. I've played around with /etc/bashrc and discovered that bash_completion allows this to work in bash, but I can't figure out how to make this work in zsh.

Comment: What version of ZSH do you have? `print $fpath[-1]/_dnf` shows a `dnf` completion script on ZSH 5.3.1.

Comment: Looks like updating zsh did it. If you post this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: FWIW, dnf does NOT have a completion script in 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZSH ships with completions in `$fpath`; these change over time especially for new and exciting programs that old and decrepit ZSH installs may know nothing about. The usual steps should be:

1. update your ZSH to the latest version and see if a completion script now exists—`print $fpath[-1]/_dnf` though for some commands the completion may exist in some other file under a `compdef` line.
2. check if the software ships with a ZSH completion script that has not be contributed to the e.g. `zsh-workers` mailing list (rare, but if so, perhaps submit that completion code to the ZSH folks so they can include it.
3. check whether some other ZSH completion repository contains completion code e.g. https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/
4. write your own completion script for the program. This typically requires studying the existing completion scripts, the `zshall(1)` docs on e.g. `_arguments` and so forth, and the usual fiddling and testing of things.

A handy command to glob the files in `$fpath` is

```
% print -l ${^fpath}/_pgrep(N)
/Users/jdoe/.zsh/functions/darwin/_pgrep
/opt/local/share/zsh/5.3.1/functions/_pgrep
%
```

which shows that on my Mac I have a custom completion for `pgrep` in addition to the upstream one.